# Use of asyndeton in a list preceded by a colon?

Tags: style, grammar

Would the word **and** be omitted before the last item in either of these two sentences?

> Maximum tree-ring counts for species sampled are as follows: American beech (50), tuliptree (125), white ash (221), sugar maple (80), red maple (~240), chestnut oak (180), sweet birch (250), **and** eastern hemlock (314)

> More steep slopes north and south of this grove included trees with the following maximum ages: tuliptree (145), chestnut oak (~314), American beech (155), **and** sweet birch (199)

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but I don't like the use of parentheses here - the things referred to before the colon are the ring counts and ages, so I would argue for either "50 (American beech), 125 (tuliptree),..." or "American beech, 50; tuliptree, 125;..."

Comment: @DM_with_secrets That's a good point, thanks for the insight.

Comment: @Nai45 Could you please tell me why you believe this question to be off-topic?

Comment: @Jack Here on Writing SE, we try not to deal with very specific grammar questions, that's English Language and Usage SE's job: https://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Nai45 Okay, thanks for the information. Should I re-post this question at https://english.stackexchange.com/ then?

Comment: @Jack Checked with mods, yes your question is fine for Writing SE, so we should leave it here. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is a matter of style. Some presctiptivist grammar texts used to insist that the "and" (or other con junction) before the final list item was required. That view is, I think, now out of date. However, it is my view that such sentences tend to flow better and are clearer with the "and" included.

Comment: @Nai45 No, i meant "now", Thanks for drawing my attention to the error. I have fixed the answer..

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used a colon in the first sentence, you can use a semi-colon after each number instead of a comma, and it would then be acceptable to drop the 'and' at the end of your sentence.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Writing SE! Thank you for the answer. You can improve your answer by providing a citation to verify your statements.